# Android theme: Whole screen becomes white

Tags: android, android-theme

I am doing a simple customization to my app where I want to add a custom background color to Action Bar. Here is my styles.xml in `styles-v14` folder. (My app is targeting only SDK 14 and above).

If I simply uncomment this line and run my app , the whole screen becomes white except status bar while I expect the Action Bar background color to be of different color.

```
 <!--     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>   -->
```

Any idea what is going wrong. Here is my App manifest:

```
 <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/btn_radio_holo_light</item>
<!--     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>   -->

  </style>


  <style name="RadioButtonAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
      <item name="android:button">@drawable/btn_radio_holo_light</item>
  </style>

  <style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
        <item name="android:background">@color/titlebackgroundcolor</item>                   
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: try this `<style name="WindowTitleBackground"> parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar"    
        <item name="android:background">@color/titlebackgroundcolor</item>`                   
    </style>

Comment: Try this: `ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));`

Comment: @Madhur Ahuja I have posted it as answer. Can you please accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `parent` attribute in your `ActionBar` style

```
<style name="WindowTitleBackground"> parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar" 
<item name="android:background">@color/titlebackgroundcolor</item>
</style>
```